# Optimizing Solr server with very high disk space

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am handling a Solr environment and learnt that Disk space utilization is 97%. Can any one help me in optimizing disk space in this scenario. When I try to optimise using below curl, File system utilization reached 100% and optimization fails.

```
curl http://solrUrl:8080/solr/dimensions1/update -H "Content-type: text/xml" --data-binary '<optimize />'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any optimize call will require that you have at least the same amount of disk space free as the size of the index, as all the segments (and documents) has to be written to new files. Unless most of your documents already are deleted, you're going to have to assume that anything less than the index size available will fail.

If you can take the server offline you can reindex from scratch (delete the index and submit all documents again), or you can move the index to a new server with enough space, optimize the index there and then copy it back to the original server and serve it from there. This will also require slight downtime, but less than doing it all from scratch.